# what is the best wat to call a fragment onListItemClick, afraid of using a large amount of fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am developing a large game guide app. The navigation for the site is through navigation drawer which has a button to to 5 games on it. Each button takes you to a ListView of characters to recruit. What I wish to happen is when you click on the list item it takes you to a fragment that displays the information for that character. But each game has over 100 characters and that could be a problem. The structure for the app is as follows

MainActivity (Drawer/Activity) > Game1 (ListView/Fragment) > Character Info (Fragment)

The character info fragment isnt created yet because I am not sure how to go about it. I have done much research into it and have a feeling I need to replace the ListView fragment with the Character fragment when a ListView Item is clicked. But how do I just call one fragment and load each characters info into that one fragment. Otherwise I will have to create over 500 fragments...that aint right. Below is the code for the ListView fragment.

**SuikodenFragment** (for game 1 - holds ListView)

```
public class SuikodenFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.suikoden_main_activity1, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    adapter = new SuikodenListAdapter(getActivity(),getModel());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.label);
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.check);
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.isChecked())
    return "is checked";
    else
    return "is not checked";
}

private List<Model> getModel() {
    list.add(new Model("Tir (Hero)"));

...more characters follow...

  }

}
```

I found [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html) which could be what I need. But as I said, I dont see how I can load character data into one fragment. Im a beginner so sorry if Im not making sense, I will try and explain further if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you can use one fragment for character detail and just display text depends on character, can't you?

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok thats what I was thinking but wasnt sure how to go about it. Im still a beginner so thinking about some of this stuff can be a little confusing

Comment: it's best approach :) http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html read this article to understand how transfer data between fragments/activity

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, then the fragment-activity created through the default templates, follows the same pattern,

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok Thank you I will look over this again as I must not have paid much attention to it the first time round

Comment: @AvinashR I am using Eclipse

Comment: Ok, the link mentioned above is enough to understand the concept. Anyway, if you're going to use AS anytime, you'd see the same.

Comment: @AvinashR Hi again, I have updated my questions and first post (with code). If you dont mind, I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction? I really dont get it at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

From a fragment you can call the activity's method, and let the activity to decide what to do; whether to replace the List or to start a new activity. The method is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

#### Explanation

in your `onItemClick`, instead of handling the navigation (i.e., creating and injecting the character fragment), you do a call to an instance of a custom Interface you specified

```
public class CharacterListFragment extends Fragment {
    public static interface OnSelectCharacterHandler() {
        void onCharacterSelect(int id);
    }

    // your code goes here...

    public void onItemClick(...) {
        // get the characterId
        ((OnSelectCharacterHandler) getActivity()).onCharacterSelect(characterId);
    }
}
```

in your Activity

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnSelectCharacterHandler {
    public void onCharacterSelect(int id) {
        // inject the character fragment or start the activity.
    }
}
```

### Suggestion

Instead of adding a number of different fragments/activities, why not try generalizing the app itself?

From what you have provided, it's clear that if there are 100 characters<sup>**3**</sup> for a single game, the user may not actually see the details of all the 100 characters<sup>**3**</sup> you have created, the user will be interested in a single character or two at a time.

For getting the details of one or two characters, it would be overkill to download a 30-40MB app, when common sense dictates that to visit the game wiki of that character(s) and add it to the offline reading list in the browser. Which means your app loses the edge.

So here are some suggestions to make the app more clean to implement and easier work with.

- Show a list of games in the main view<sup>**1**</sup>. (using `NavigationDrawer`/`GridView`/`ListView`/*you name it*)
- Generalize the character view, for a single game.<sup>**2**</sup> (show HP, MP,...)
- Populate the generalized character view from the source<sup>**1**</sup>. No need to create different fragments for different characters.

*1: get the source from remote url, cache it locally.*

*2: you can go ahead and generalize the character screen for other games, or use different view for different games.*

*3: if there are `n` games, then the fragments created in the current approach will reach `n*100`*

***Advanced***: instead of storing **all** the data locally, you can remove the data which is least used by the user once a limit is reached.

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful! When you refer to  remote url, are you referring to using a mysql database? Because I have been looking into that. Then loading the correct data based on which character I'd is clicked?

Comment: @theCreed, remote url usually is a REST client, from there, you sync the data with the local database. If you'd like to implement something like that, see this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE . If you think that this is too much for you, then I'd suggest doing simple REST client and learn the platform first before diving deep.

Comment: @theCreed if this answers the question, then please mark it as answered.